# What is the pattern for an Iphone app with both a View Controller and Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to write an `iPhone` app that has both a `UITabBar` controller (and its associated views) and a plain `vanilla` view controller that is *not* part of the `TabBar` (i.e. an initial config page that only gets displayed the first time the app is run).
I am able to put a `Tab Bar` Controller and a View Controller in `MainWindow.xib` and shuffle between the two in the app delegate. 
 While this works I'm wondering if this is the best way to be implementing this.
It doesn't feel very "MVC-ish" to me but I think the two different controllers both need to be root (?)
I don't know how else I would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the config page is really only a "run once" affair, you could just pop it as a modal view from within the tab bar controller via the presentModalViewController:animated: method. (If on the other hand the config page is *ever* likely to be required in the future, I'd just add it as another option on the UITabBar.)

Comment: I would go with a modal view as this responder suggests.  This is a perfect example for their use.  This way, you can check if the settings were set by the user, if not, show the modal view on startup.  Then from there, the settings bundle would be accessed via the Settings page on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You would make the tabbarcontroller the default view. And present the viewcontroller modally in viewWillAppear or similar method. Then when you want to switch to the tabbar, you'd dismiss the modal view controller.